# Use express.js functions in external file classes

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to use functions of express.js in an object but I don't know how to achieve this:

My **app.js**

```
var app = express();
var myfunc = require('./script');
myfunc.test('This is a test')
```

My **script.js**

```
console.log('script.js file loaded ...');
module.exports = 
{
    test: function(message)
    {
        console.log('|-----> test('+ message +')');
    }
};
```

My idea is to be able to use functions from app ( *express()* ) within the function called test in script.js, something like:

```
console.log('script.js file loaded ...');
    module.exports = 
    {
        test: function(message)
        {
            app.post('/', function (req, res) {
                res.send('POST request to homepage');
            });
            console.log('|-----> test('+ message +')');
        }
    };
```

How could I use post inside this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common approach is to scope required instances by making `module.exports` a function and passing whatever you need to initialize a module.

app.js

```
 var app = express();
 var myFunc = require('./script')(app);
```

script.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {
   return {
     test: function(message) {
        app.post('/', function (req, res) {
            res.send('POST request to homepage');
        });
        console.log('|-----> test('+ message +')');
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your app.js you can register other express objects as middleware, so in your script.js you can export an express object and use it in app.js to register the routes specified in the other file.

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var scriptRoutes = require('./script.js');
app.use(scriptRoutes);
```

script.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('/', function(req, res, next){
  res.status(200).send("POST request made to homepage");
};

module.exports = app;
```